# state seems to switch from widget to widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I was building a todo list app which uses a `ListView.builder` to render multiple task widgets which have three properties, title, checked, and starred. It works just fine until I star/check an existing task and add a new task, in which case the state of the previous task seems to jump to the newly added task. What could be causing the problem? Could this have something to do with keys?

```dart
class Main extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Main> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<Main> {
  var todoList = [];
  var stars = 0;
  void addStar() {
    setState(() {
      stars++;
    });
  }

  void removeStar() {
    if (stars > 0) {
      setState(() {
        stars--;
      });
    }
  }

  void addTodo(title) {
    setState(() {
      todoList.add(title);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: Builder(builder: (context) {
          return FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return NewTodo(addTodo: addTodo);
                  });
            },
          );
        }),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      'My Day',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 28, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                            'IMPORTANT: ',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                              letterSpacing: 1.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 58, 58, 58),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '$stars',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 24.0,
                                letterSpacing: 1.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 147, 8)),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert, size: 24),
                            onPressed: () => {print('more ...')},
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  // height: 300,
                  child: todoList.length == 0
                      ? Text('No Tasks Yet ',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 24.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              color: Colors.grey))
                      : ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: todoList.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Todo(
                                title: todoList[(todoList.length - 1) - index],
                                addStar: addStar,
                                removeStar: removeStar);
                          }))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the app currently only has three files, below is a link to the gist.

https://gist.github.com/FENETMULER/eb4a898b82f9aa4c6a871a1fa9833c84

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue? More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have included a gist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `Key`s with a `ListView` and not a `ListView.builder` as it doesn't seem to work with `ListView.builder`, the problem actually comes from **reversing** the list, since when the list is reversed every time a new task is added the objects in the `Widget Tree` won't be in line with their corresponding Object in the `Element Tree`.

```
ListView(children: todoList.reversed.map((title) => Todo(title: title, key: ValueKey(title))).toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your logic like

```dart
: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: todoList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Todo(
          title: todoList[index], //this
          addStar: addStar,
          removeStar: removeStar);
    },
  ),
```

Comment: but why wouldn't it work when it was rendered in reverse?

Comment: if you like to reverse the list use `reverse` parameter on  `ListView.builder(`

Comment: When I used the reverse parameter the main problem has been fixed but the list now starts from the bottom of the screen, and I really want to understand why my first logic was causing that issue?

Comment: I suspect adding list and using callback, perhaps you can create a todo data class with start and checked bool. Or you can use `insert` instead of `.add` on last time like `todoList.insert(todoList.isEmpty ? 0 : todoList.length - 1, title);`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have this line:

```
title: todoList[(todoList.length - 1) - index],
```

Let's imagine you have 3 items in the list `list = [1,2,3];` The `ListView.builder` should iterate through them by saying

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Text(list[index].toString());
    },
```

This way, the **ListView.builder Widget** will return a text with '1', '2' and '3' in this order since you call list[index] for the length of list (3 times) and each time index increments (starting from 0) so you call list[0], list[1] and list [2] (which return the three texts '1', '2' and '3'.)
 You, however, call `list[(list.length-1) - index]`, so when index iterates from 0 to 2 you get:
list [ 3 - 1 - 0 ] = list [2] = text '3'
list [ 3 - 1 - 1 ] = list [1] = text '2'
list [ 3 - 1 - 2 ] = list [0] = text '1'
with this you can clearly see that you get a reverse list, hence, if you use `list.reversed`, you will get the correct list.

Comment: Yes, added that logic so that the list would be iterated from last to first,  so that the newly added task will be on top, but the problem with this (when reversed in any way) is that for example if a task is starred, when a new task is added the state of the previous task seems to transfer to the newly added task. And this seems to happen only when the list is reversed (either using the .reversed getter or when read from last to first item).